# Creating new blocks with Sir Trevor using selenium webdriver (C#)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sirtrevor

So I am trying to target the + symbol on the bottom rather than the top using Sir Trevor here http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/example.html in order to create a new block below.

Anything I try pretty much returns an element not found.

for example:
(driver.findelement(by.cssselector("blahblah")).click();

I am not sure how to target pseudo elements such as ::after or if it is even possible. Or perhaps I am going about it all wrong. Looking for some insight into this, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 0):

you can use following xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.className("st-block-controls__top")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("st-block-8")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("st-block-10")).click();
```

Comment: hope you wrote the code for java, it seems to be valid

Answer (score -1):

From the link what you gave i.e. http://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/example.html

**I can find three + symbol**

Please find the Xpath for all the three + symbol at that webpage

**First + symbol**

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='st-block-controls__top']")).Click();
```

**Second + symbol (middle)**

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='st-block-8']")).Click();
```

**Last + symbol (last)**

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='st-block-10']")).Click();
```